# How to resize canvas interactively in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop, canvas

If I resize canvas from menu, then the size of larger objects not change. I.e. they still have some portions existing outside of canvas.

Meanwhile, if I do crop with interactive tool, I loose outside data.

Is it possible to change canvas as if I do cropping, i.e. with the same visual instruments, but without loosing data?

Answer (score 3):

With the **Crop Tool** selected, simply **uncheck** the "Delete Cropped Pixels" option in the **Control Bar**.

[image]